# Fixed block вопрос при закреплении

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть страница

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
    .top {
      /* ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА */
      /*position: fixed;*/
      float: left;
      color: red;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .left {
      margin: auto;
      top: 100;
      bottom: 100;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 45%;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .right {
      /*fixed*/
      float: left;
      color: black;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 55%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .img {
      width: 128px;
      height: 160px;
    }
  </style>

  <title>lol</title>
</head>

<body>




  <a class="top">a</a>
  <a class="left">a</a>

  <a class="right">

  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

Как сделать что два нижних блока имели отсуп от верхнего фиксорованого и они шли под фиксированый блок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  /* для наглядности */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 120, 0, 1.0), rgba(200, 150, 0, .7));
}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  float: left;
  /* для наглядности */
  background-color: #777;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(200, 0, 0, .5) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 0, .5) 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.right {
  width: 55%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  float: left;
  /* для наглядности */
  background-color: #777;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), linear-gradient(120deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px
}

.img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a class="top">TOP</a>
<a class="left">LEFT</a>
<a class="right">RIGHT</a>
```